# Set beanstalk subdomain in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk

In web console I can choose any subdomain I like for my beanstalk environment
[image]

How can I achieve this in CDK (typescript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be set in `cnamePrefix`

```
const website_env = new aws_elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
    cnamePrefix: 'some-sub-domain', 
    ...
}
```

The complete domain then becomes `some-sub-domain.${this.region}.elasticbeanstalk.com`